Variable Value Inconsistency in GDB When Using 'info variables' and 'print' Commands
In the same process, when debugging with GDB and inspecting the variable grpc_client_handle_msg, I first used the info variables command and then printed its value, obtaining a normal value:
#gdb attach 100
(gdb) info variables grpc_client_handle_msg
All variables matching regular expression "grpc_client_handle_msg":
File lib/grpc.c:
21:    P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG *grpc_client_handle_msg;
Non-debugging symbols:
0x000000000096c698  grpc_client_handle_msg
(gdb) p grpc_client_handle_msg
$1 = (P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG *) 0x773c000
(gdb)

However, when I first print its information and then use the info variables command, the value is 0x0:
#gdb attach 100
(gdb) p grpc_client_handle_msg
$1 = (P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG *) 0x0
(gdb) info variables grpc_client_handle_msg
All variables matching regular expression "grpc_client_handle_msg":
File lib/grpc.c:
21:    P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG *grpc_client_handle_msg;
(gdb) p grpc_client_handle_msg
$2 = (P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG *) 0x0
(gdb)

During these two operations, there was no intentional modification to the value.I try 10 times, when used info variables first, the variable value is always 0x773c000, and when used print first, the variable value is always 0x0.
I found grpc_client_handle_msg are two different variables when I print the address of variables. When I info variables first, the address is
(gdb) p &grpc_client_handle_msg
$2 = (P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG **) 0x96c698 <grpc_client_handle_msg>

But when i print first, the address is
(gdb)p &grpc_client_handle_msg
$2 = (P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG **) 0x7fd42e28af98 <grpc_client_handle_msg>

The variable declare in grpc.c:
P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG *grpc_client_handle_msg = NULL;

And extern in grpc.h:
typedef int (*P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG)(struct zclient *, struct json_object *, char *);
extern P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG *grpc_client_handle_msg;

Used in other.c:
#include "lib/grpc.h" // grpc_client_handle_msg extern here
void zebra_grpc_init(struct thread_master *master, int redist_default,
             unsigned short instance, struct zebra_privs_t *privs)
{
    ...
    grpc_client_handle_msg = XCALLOC(
        MTYPE_TMP, sizeof(P_GRPC_CLIENT_HANDLE_MSG) * GNMI_MAX_VAL);
    grpc_client_handle_msg[GNMI_SET_ZEBRA_INTERFACE_ADDR] = zebra_handle_grpc_setunset_zebra_interface_address;
    ...
}


When you attach to the process, is the state exactly the same in both cases?

Doesn't the first output of info variables suggest you have 2 different variables with the same name, one with debug info, and one without?

@Someprogrammerdude: They are same process and same variables;

@ssbssa Yes, they are two different variables, I print the address of variables. You can see the detail info bellow.

First off, you should edit the additional information into the question, and not make it an answer. So this are actually 2 variables, and from the addresses it looks like they are in 2 different shared libraries. So why do you expect a different result? Maybe you should also add how you declare the variable in the sources and headers.

They are not the "same" variables, because they are in different processes. And state of the two processes might be different, they might have done different things to come to the same point in the code. To be able to compare memory contents of two different processes started from the same executable program file, you need to be 100% sure that there is no differences at all in the execution of the two processes. Everything must be exactly equal.

@Someprogrammerdude They are the same process, the process ID is the same one.  I used gdb attach xxx, the xxx is the same process ID.

Is this on Linux?

@ssbssa Yes, linux kernel version "Linux xxx.host 4.19.91-012.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Sep 15 17:27:09 CST 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux".

Are grpc.c and other.c part of the same shared library? In which shared library do each of the addresses 0x96c698 and 0x7fd42e28af98 belong to?

@ssbssa grpc.c in library A, other.c used -L load library A.

If it's the same process, but you attach at different times, the state of the process ad of the variable might have changed between those two points in time. You need to trace your code to see what really happens. Add a lot of logging output to see what's going on, unless it's not too much and you can use the debugger to just step through it with a watch on the variable.

There might also be undefined behavior somewhere else in the code, which overwrites the value of the variable. Build and run with sanitizers (-fsanitize=address,undefined) to help catch such cases.

@Someprogrammerdude The variable grpc_client_handle_msg only init when the process start, and I try 10 times, if i used info variables first, it's value is 0x96c698, otherwise is 0x7fd42e28af98, so the value of grpc_client_handle_msg must not be changed between those two points.

Like I said, you could have undefined behavior somewhere in the code you don't show us, which could do anything. Without a proper [mre] it's really impossible for us to help you debug your problem. All we can really do is guess.
